# how to create custome folder in php server while uploading file to server in unity?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, server, upload

I use the below codes to upload images to a server from unity with help of PHP. but it only uploads to a single folder named "uploaded_images". I want to create custom folders based on login id. How to do that. how to send custom folder names to PHP. I am not that good at programming, so I copied this code from Github. Anyone, please help. thanks in advance

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['myimage'])){

    $img = $_FILES['myimage']['name'];
    $tmpimg = $_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'];

    //To get file extension
    //$fileExt = pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) ;

    move_uploaded_file($tmpimg, "./uploaded_images/$img");

    echo "[success] image ($img) uploaded successfully.";
    exit();
}
else{
    echo "[error] there is no data with name [myimage]";
}

?>
```

these are  the c#  scripts used

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    [SerializeField] string serverUrl;
    [SerializeField] Image ImageBox;
    public string name_of_Image;


    

    public void upload()
    {
        ImageUploader
            .Initialize ()
            .SetUrl (serverUrl)
            .SetTexture (ImageBox.sprite.texture)
            .SetFieldName ("myimage")
            .SetFileName (name_of_Image)
            .SetType (ImageType.JPG)
            .OnError (error => Debug.Log (error))
            .OnComplete (text => Debug.Log (text))
            .Upload ();
    }
}


public class ImageUploader : MonoBehaviour
{
    Texture2D imageTexture;
    string fieldName;
    string fileName = "defaultImageName";
    ImageType imageType = ImageType.PNG;
    string url;

    //Events
    UnityAction<string> OnErrorAction;
    UnityAction<string> OnCompleteAction;


    public static ImageUploader Initialize ()
    {
        return new GameObject ("ImageUploader").AddComponent <ImageUploader> ();
    }

    public ImageUploader SetUrl (string serverUrl)
    {
        this.url = serverUrl;
        return this;
    }

    public ImageUploader SetTexture (Texture2D texture)
    {
        this.imageTexture = texture;
        return this;
    }

    public ImageUploader SetFileName (string filename)
    {
        this.fileName = filename;
        return this;
    }

    public ImageUploader SetFieldName (string fieldName)
    {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        return this;
    }

    public ImageUploader SetType (ImageType type)
    {
        this.imageType = type;
        return this;
    }
    //events
    public ImageUploader OnError (UnityAction<string> action)
    {
        this.OnErrorAction = action;
        return this;
    }

    public ImageUploader OnComplete (UnityAction<string> action)
    {
        this.OnCompleteAction = action;
        return this;
    }

    public void Upload ()
    {
        //check/validate fields
        if (url == null)
            Debug.LogError ("Url is not assigned, use SetUrl( url ) to set it. ");
        //...other checks...
        //...

        StopAllCoroutines ();
        StartCoroutine (StartUploading ());
    }



    IEnumerator StartUploading ()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
        byte[] textureBytes = null;

        //Get a copy of the texture, because we can't access original texure data directly. 
        Texture2D imageTexture_copy = GetTextureCopy (imageTexture);

        switch (imageType) {
            case ImageType.PNG:
                textureBytes = imageTexture_copy.EncodeToPNG ();
                break;
            case ImageType.JPG:
                textureBytes = imageTexture_copy.EncodeToJPG ();
                break;
        }

        //image file extension
        string extension = imageType.ToString ().ToLower ();

        form.AddBinaryData (fieldName, textureBytes, fileName + "." + extension, "image/" + extension);

        WWW w = new WWW (url, form);

        yield return w;

        if (w.error != null) {
            //error : 
            if (OnErrorAction != null)
                OnErrorAction (w.error); //or OnErrorAction.Invoke (w.error);
        } else {
            //success
            if (OnCompleteAction != null)
                OnCompleteAction (w.text); //or OnCompleteAction.Invoke (w.error);
        }
        w.Dispose ();
        Destroy (this.gameObject);
    }

    Texture2D GetTextureCopy (Texture2D source)
    {
        //Create a RenderTexture
        RenderTexture rt = RenderTexture.GetTemporary (
                               source.width,
                               source.height,
                               0,
                               RenderTextureFormat.Default,
                               RenderTextureReadWrite.Linear
                           );

        //Copy source texture to the new render (RenderTexture) 
        Graphics.Blit (source, rt);

        //Store the active RenderTexture & activate new created one (rt)
        RenderTexture previous = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture.active = rt;

        //Create new Texture2D and fill its pixels from rt and apply changes.
        Texture2D readableTexture = new Texture2D (source.width, source.height);
        readableTexture.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, rt.width, rt.height), 0, 0);
        readableTexture.Apply ();

        //activate the (previous) RenderTexture and release texture created with (GetTemporary( ) ..)
        RenderTexture.active = previous;
        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary (rt);

        return readableTexture;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your upload is working with uploaded_files folder then you can change your server code like below.

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['myimage'])){
    $userId = $_GET['userId']//or $_POST
    $img = $_FILES['myimage']['name'];
    $tmpimg = $_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'];

    //To get file extension
    //$fileExt = pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) ;
    if (!file_exists('./uploaded_images/$userId')) {
        mkdir('./uploaded_images/$userId', 0777, true);
    }
    move_uploaded_file($tmpimg, "./uploaded_images/$userId/$img");

    echo "[success] image ($img) uploaded successfully.";
    exit();
}
else{
    echo "[error] there is no data with name [myimage]";
}

?>
```

And you can send userId from Unity3d client file.
I hope it can work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the replay .can you please show me what should I add to my c# script too? that will be great help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: at startuploading function you can add like this after this code below.
 form.AddBinaryData (fieldName, textureBytes, fileName + "." + extension, "image/" + extension);
form.AddField("userId", userId);

Comment: that worked thannks

Comment: one more dought. please help. what change i need to do to the original Php code to make a folder in the name of the image file I am uploading? that is actually the login id.

Comment: explain exactly. image name folder or userid folder?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need to create a folder that is the same name as the image that is uploaded. I believe the name is already passed to the PHP.

Comment: if (!file_exists('./uploaded_images/$img')) {
        mkdir('./uploaded_images/$img', 0777, true);
    }